# how to spec a lazy-seq generating function?

Tags: clojure, clojure.spec

I wish to use spec in my pre and post conditions of a generator function. A simplified example of what I wish to do is described below:

```
(defn positive-numbers
  ([]
   {:post [(s/valid? (s/+ int?) %)]}
   (positive-numbers 1))
  ([n]
   {:post [(s/valid? (s/+ int?) %)]}
   (lazy-seq (cons n (positive-numbers (inc n))))))

(->> (positive-numbers) (take 5))
```

However, defining the generator function like that seems to cause stack-overflow, the cause being that spec will eagerly try to evaluate the whole thing, -or something like that....

**Is there another way of using spec to describe the `:post` result of a generator function like the one above (without causing stack-overflow)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theoretically correct answer is that in general you cannot check whether a lazy sequence matches a spec without realizing all of it.

In the case of your specific example of `(s/+ int?)`, given a lazy sequence, how would one establish merely by observing the sequence whether all its elements are integers? However many elements you examine, the next one could always be a keyword.

This is the sort of thing that a type system like, say, [core.typed](https://github.com/clojure/core.typed) may be able to prove, but a runtime-predicate-based assertion won't be able to check.

Now, in addition to `s/+` and `s/*`, spec (as of Clojure 1.9.0-alpha14) also has a a combinator called `s/every`, whose docstring says this:

> Note that 'every' does not do exhaustive checking, rather it samples *coll-check-limit* elements.

So we have e.g.

```
(s/valid? (s/* int?) (concat (range 1000) [:foo]))
;= false
```

but

```
(s/valid? (s/every int?) (concat (range 1000) [:foo]))
;= true
```

(with the default `*coll-check-limit*` value of `101`).

This actually isn't an immediate fix to your example – plugging in `s/every` in place of `s/+` won't work, because each recursive call will want to validate its own return value, which will involve realizing more of the sequence, which will involve more recursive calls etc. But you could factor out the sequence-building logic to a helper function with no postconditions and then have `positive-numbers` declare the postcondition and call that helper function:

```
(defn positive-numbers* [n]
  (lazy-seq (cons n (positive-numbers* (inc n)))))

(defn positive-numbers [n]
  {:post [(s/valid? (s/every int? :min-count 1) %)]}
  (positive-numbers* n))
```

Note the caveats:

1. this will still realize a good chunk of your sequence, which may wreak havoc with your application's performance profile;
2. the only watertight guarantee here is that the prefix actually examined is as desired, if the seq has a weird item at position 123456, that will go unnoticed.

Because of (1), this is something that makes more sense as a test-only assertion. (2) may be acceptable – you'll still catch some silly typos and the documentation value of the spec is there anyway; if it isn't and you do want an absolutely watertight guarantee that your return type is as desired, then again, core.typed (perhaps used locally just for a handful of namespaces) may be the better bet.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate answer. I think `:gen-max` should be used instead of `:min-count` though.
Another thing I noted is that these pre and post conditions with spec are incredible punishing wrt performance. -So I will probably create `fdef` specs instead.
I am very new to clojure, and coming from type checked languages such as F#/Haskell/Idris I really miss not only the assurances provided by type checkers but most importantly the documentation value which types provide. -I will definitely have a close look at core.typed as soon as time permits.

Comment: `:gen-max` is used to control generation (as employed by things like `s/exercise` and `clojure.spec.test/check`) and has no impact on what data satisfy the spec. `:min-count` is part of the spec – it imposes an additional condition on the size of the collections that can be deemed to satisfy the spec. I put it in because you used `s/+` rather than `s/*` in the question. Agreed re: spec assertions being punishing w.r.t. performance. For that reason, they should only be used at test/dev time. Also agreed about `fdef`, it's definitely the best approach to attaching specs here.